# CodeBlocks with MinGW: dll missing on runtime

Tags: c++, dll, codeblocks

Even when running some "Hello World" programs, I get missing dll error on runtime. Copying .dll to .exe folder obviously works but it's a dumb solution for `std::cout << "abc";`.

These are my compiler setting. After adding linking options (bottom right corner) the error just went from one dll to another (libwinpthread-1.dll).

[image]

Comment: Hit the auto detect and make sure that the folder bin is inside the folder miggw32

Comment: @ArunA.S I did and it didn't change any settings. bin folder is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by adding -static -lpthread to my linking commands.